# Validating Select Fields in Flask WTF Forms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am using Flask-WTF forms and I have the following code:

in forms.py

```python
class DealForm( Form ):
    country  = SelectField( 'Country' )
```

in main.py

```python
if not form.validate_on_submit():
    form = DealForm()
    form.country.choices = [('us','USA'),('gb','Great Britain'),('ru','Russia')]
    return render_template( 'index.html', user = current_user, form = form )
else:
    return render_template( 'index.html', form = form )
```

It gets an error when I return from the POST because the country.choices is None
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

You need to set the choices before calling `validate_on_submit()`.

Since they are static do it when creating the Form class:

```
class DealForm(Form):
    country = SelectField('Country', choices=[
        ('us','USA'),('gb','Great Britain'),('ru','Russia')])
```

If you wanted to set them after creating the form instance, e.g. because the available choices are not hardcoded or different depending on other factors, you'd do it like this after creating the instance of the class:

```
form.country.choices = [('us','USA'),('gb','Great Britain'),('ru','Russia')]
```

I.e. just like you already did but earlier.